# Laptop booting several times before really starting

Tags: windows, boot, laptop, acer-aspire

So my laptop (Acer Aspire E15) with Intel Celeron Processor doesn't boot properly. When I press the start button the blue light turns on and it makes some sounds as if the computer will turn on but then it turns off. Then this is being repeated (2 - 7 times) and then the laptop turns really on. I don't know what caused the problem since I don't rememmber downloading any software before it occured. The laptop was bought about year ago with installed Windows 8. After the upgrade to Windows 10 the problem remained.

I wanted to startup in Safe mode but I'm not very sure how this could help me. So I would be glad if anybody can help me.

Acer Aspire E15
Intel Celeron Processor N2830
Intel HD Graphics
4 GB DDR3 L Memory
500 GB HDD

I don't know what information you would need. Therefore ask please in the comments.

**[update]**

So thanks a lot for the answer @Ethan Z. I don't know how to make it accepted answer since I posted the question as unregistered user. Today as I tried to fix the problem it become even more evident that some connections inside the laptop are not working properly. Once it booted so as if every moment it would start up but it suddenly turned off. So thanks for the advice.

Comment: You can request an account merger via the "contact us" link at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Booting into safe mode wouldn't change anything. This is an issue with your computer, not Windows. Windows is a software that runs on the computer, but the startup sequence until you see "Starting windows" is the computer's kernel and BIOS.

I am going to assume that there are no additional beeps coming out of the computer and the screen never displays anything or you likely would have said so. It's likely that there is a broken or loose piece of hardware in the laptop. I'm going to suggest you bring it in for repair before it doesn't turn on. If you have a lot of computer skills you could repair a desktop yourself, but laptops are notoriously difficult to repair. Make sure you backup all of your data ASAP.